# Can I create a mutt macro to reply and archive?

Tags: mutt

Is it possible to create a (`neo`)`mutt` macro to reply to an email, then move it to another folder? Currently I have the following two macros defined.

```
bind index,pager r group-reply
macro pager a ":set confirmappend=no delete=yes<enter><clear-flag>N<enter><save-message>${my_archive}<enter><sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes delete=ask-yes<enter>"
```

The first replies to the current message. The second marks email as read and moves it to my "archive" folder. After replying to an email, I almost always move it to the archive folder.

Is there a way to combine the two macros into one command? I don't care if it replies then archives, or archives then replies.

Comment: I think your needs could be solved with reply-hook neomuttrc(5).

Comment: Thanks @JakubJindra. I just updated this question slightly. Rather than a command that archives *every* time, I'd prefer a separate macro that does it only when explicitly called.